# Domain can't connect with RDP between PC

Tags: active-directory, domain

I can't connect via RDP, between PC in domain.

From SRV I see another PC and I can connect with that PC, but connection between PC doesn't work.

Why?

[image]

Comment: From SRV i can ping PC 1 and PC 2 
but i cant ping from PC1 to PC2

Comment: What is "SRV"? Do you mean "Server"? If so, can you please use that term in the question, as it is more meaningful and easier to understand when you use the full proper name. What are the PCs network configurations? Are they on the same subnet?